# file upload does not work in IE 8, IE 9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

i have the following code to upload a file, which runs without error in mozilla firefox and google chrome but gives error in IE 8. Please provide solution. This is my view-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input_panelleft">
            <div class="input_panellabel">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrawingName)
            </div>
            <div class="input_panelinput">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DrawingName)
            </div>
            <div class="input_panellabel">
                Upload Drawing
            </div>
            <div class="input_panelinput">
                <input type="file" name='file' id='file' />
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and following code in controller-

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(DrawingDocumentsModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var documentNameParts = file.FileName.Split('.');
                var documentExtension = documentNameParts.Last();
                var documentNameOnly = String.Join(".", documentNameParts.Take(documentNameParts.Length - 1));
                var filename = documentNameOnly + "." + documentExtension;
                if (_drawingDocumentService.IsDrawingNameAvailable(filename))
                {
                    var path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                    var Filepath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
                    file.SaveAs(Filepath);

                    var drawingDocuments = new DrawingDocuments();
                    drawingDocuments.ProjectId = 1;
                    drawingDocuments.ProjectName = "Drawing Tag";
                    drawingDocuments.FileName = filename;
                    drawingDocuments.UploadedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                    drawingDocuments.UploadedBy = _workContext.CurrentUserId;
                    if (model.DrawingName == "" || model.DrawingName == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Please Enter Drawing Name");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        drawingDocuments.DrawingName = model.DrawingName;
                        drawingDocuments.Path = ("/Uploads/" + filename);

                        _drawingDocumentService.InsertDrawingDocument(drawingDocuments);
                        return RedirectToAction("DrawingDocuments");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Drawing With Same File Name Already Available");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Please Select Drawing");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Internet explorer cannot open this page.

Comment: And what it tells? Not Found? Internal Server Error? If you want to get some help - provide info which can help others to see what is wrong.

Comment: The error is-The website cannot display the page. most likely causes- website under maintenance. website has programming errors. what you can try- refresh the page. go back to previous page. more information.

Comment: What is the page that IE is trying to open? Did you try to debug it and see where the error occurs?

Comment: there is no error since code runs fine on other browsers.link pasted below has image that IE opens- HTTP 500 internal server error